Alternative solution to Google TTS API in creating TTS Windows app with Python
I am making a text to speech software on Windows OS using Python. I found the google text to speech api. It's pretty good, but I want it to use in offline with downloadable speech packs like Speech Recognition and Synthesis from Google on Android. Even on Android it is free, while the API only allows a maximum of 4 million free characters. I want to ask is there any other way, I can create a similar application on Windows?  P/s: this is my first post here, I hope everyone can help.
I tried to find some other solutions like gTTS library. However, it is not as diverse as the Google TTS API
